# VUE Image with :src doesnt show up on first rendering

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-storage

Hello i'm facing an issue on my avatar component, the image that i load from an url stocked in my vuex store doesn't show up on the first rendering, only at the second.

here's my avatar component

```
<template>
   <img :src="getAvatarUrl()"/>
</template>

<script>
export default {
 methods: {
   getAvatarUrl() {
     return this.$store.state.user.userAvatarUrl
   }
 }
}
</script>
```

here's how i commit the image url in my store from App.vue:

```
  created() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      if (user) {
        let avatarRef = firebase.storage().ref().child(`avatars/${this.$store.state.user.displayName}`)
        avatarRef.getDownloadURL().then(url => {
          this.$store.commit('userAvatarUrl', url)
        })
      }
   })
}
```

This image from the avatar component doesn't render the first time it should,
I have to navigate on another route and come back to see it.
I tried to force rerender on all lifecycle hooks with :key and use this.$nexttick but that don't work too.
Thanks for the help

Comment: test:
data: () => ({
 avatar: ''
})
created () {
 this.avatar = this.getAvatarUrl()
}
<template>
   <img :src="avatar"/>
</template>

Comment: @HamiltonGabriel tried it right now, and the image doesn't load at all, even if i navigate to another route :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the store doesn't contain the image path until the request has completed and the request will likely complete *after* the DOM and your component has rendered.

You just need to use a [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) instead:

```
<template>
   <img :src="avatarUrl"/>
</template>

<script>
export default {
 computed: {
   avatarUrl() {
     return this.$store.state.user.userAvatarUrl
   }
 }
}
</script>
```